# Can't handle unfamiliar date format in BigQuery

Tags: sql, date, error-handling, google-bigquery, casting

I'm trying to query a BigQuery table that has column "date" (set to type DATE in the schema) formatted as yyyy-mm-dd-??. In other words, there's an extra set of information about the date and I'm not really sure what it is. When I try to query the "date" column I run into the error:

SQL Error [100032] [HY000]: [Simba]BigQueryJDBCDriver Error executing query job. Message: Invalid date: '2022-09-03-01'

I've tried cast(date as string), cast(left(date, 10) as string), all types of workarounds, but the error persists. It seems that no matter how much I try and nail it home in the query that I want this weird date column to be read as a string, so that I can work with it, BigQuery still wants to take it as a date, I guess because that's how it's setup in the schema. I don't care if this is parsed into a date properly or if it's read as a string and then I can parse it from there, I just want to be able to query the date column without getting an error.

Comment: How odd. Am I right in thinking you're trying to read this from a Java programme, rather than the BigQuery UI? If so, have you tried querying this column via the UI, and does that also fail?

Comment: Possible to add a screenshot of the data/schema in BQ?